# how to use a javascript function with secure setting in Zendesk app

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

want to use a javascript function on a secure setting

```
"parameters": [
    {
      "name": "api_token",
      "type": "text",
      "required": true,
      "secure": true
    }
  ]
```

using above setting

```
var settings = {
  URL: "Some url",
  headers: {"Authorization": `Basic ${btoa{{apiKey}}}`},
  secure: true,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/app-developer-guide/using-the-apps-framework/#using-secure-settings), in order to perform requests with secure settings, you need to:

- add a `secure: true` property to the parameter
- replace the sensitive information in the code with a placeholder
- define a `domainWhitelist` property in the manifest file, as only requests to the white-listed domains will work for secure requests

I see two issues with your code:

1. If your setting name is `api_token`, then the placeholder you need to use is `{{setting.api_token}}`
2. As the placeholder is replaced on the proxy layer, `${btoa("{{apiKey}}")}` would not work the way you expect, i.e. you would be literally encoding the string `{{apiKey}}`, which would then no longer act as a placeholder. If you need a base-64 encoded string, you should save the base-64 encoded string as your `api_token` parameter